# HTTP link from HTTPS website

Tags: http, ssl, https

If I move a website to https so that it loads all resources (css, js, images, ...) via https, the browser will not pop any warning (I hope).

However, what if the content of my site is partially created by another users who may have already added links, e.g. `<a href=http://anothersite.com>"`, that target websites without https. In such case, will the browser warn about mixed content?

And what about images, e.g. `<img src=http://anothersite.com/img.jpg>"`?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: @GhyathSerhal no, I don't want to risk it on production server, that's why I tried SO in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A link will not trigger mixed-content**:

The content of that link is not displayed on your page, it doesn't modify the appearance or the functionalities of your page, so no reason to display a mixed-content warning.

(But if a secure version of that website is available, it's better to link directly to it, to avoid an insecure redirect)

But **http images included in your https pages will trigger mixed-content warnings**

What you cant do to prevent it partially, it using HSTS and https://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/